# Async Await with Mongoose Returns Empty Object

Tags: express, async-await, es6-promise

I have my mongoose schema for a user's profile where they can add work experience (currently an array of objects in schema).

I have used the following code to find the user's profile and get the experience object as input then attach it to the array in schema and return the saved profile with experience:

```
Router.post('/experience',
Passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), async (req, res) => {
try {
    const myProfile = await Profile.findOne({user: req.user._id});

    if (myProfile) {
        const exp = {
            title: req.body.title,
            company: req.body.company,
            location: req.body.location,
            from: req.body.from,
            to: req.body.to,
            isCurrent: req.body.isCurrent,
            description: req.body.description
        };
        // add to Profile experience array
        Profile.experience.unshift(exp); // adds to beginning of array
        const savedProfile = await Profile.save(); // have also tried myProfile.save() but that doesn't work too
        if (savedProfile) {
            console.log(savedProfile);
            res.json({message: `Profile Updated Successfully`, details: savedProfile})
        }
        else { throw `Experience Details Not Saved`}
    }

} catch (err) { res.json(err); }
});
```

The problem here is that the response is always an empty object and when I check my database, there is no experience saved. Is this code wrong? Same thing works with Promises but I want to try a new way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

The `async-await` pattern is another way to write `Promise`, the return value of the function is `Promise.resolve(result)` or `Promise.reject(reason)` of the whole async.

In the outer function, `Router.post` in this case, it has to use `async-await`, or `then` of `Promise` pattern, to deal with the returned `Promise`. Orelse, the `async` function would not have chance to run, as the returned `Promise` would be omitted.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with Promises. The problem here is when saving the added experience object. I have logged the Profile from Profile.findOne() but not able to save it