# Mongoose returns undefined even with await. Any guess of may be wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am testing some functionalities in mongoose, I want o learn new things. I am playing with subdocuments. Consider the code below. Why is doc printed as undefined? I am using await, it should wait, shouldn’t it?

```
pushSubdocument();//calls the function

async function pushSubdocument() {
  const doc = await findByIdMongoose(); //I ask to await
  console.log(doc);//I am printing here, and it is undefined
}
function findByIdMongoose() {
  Document.findById({ _id: "5e6d0f3e8afae22ee0cc238c" })
    .select("friends")
    .then(doc => {
        doc.friends.push({
        name: "Maria",
        email: "mariadomar@test.com",
        relatives: []
      });

      doc.save().then(() => {
        console.log("saved!");
      });
// if I print it here, before returning, it is okay
      return doc;
    });
}
```

Related question:  [Async Await with Mongoose Returns Empty Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639230/async-await-with-mongoose-returns-empty-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findByIdMongoose()` will return undefined because ,the doc you are trying to return from it will get returned after this function gets called `asynchronous nature of node js`. And there is no reason to await `non async` function `findByIdMongoose()`.

You can do something like this

```
async function pushSubdocument() {
  const doc = await findByIdMongoose(); //I ask to await
  console.log(doc);//I am printing here, and it is undefined
}
async function findByIdMongoose() {

let doc= await Document.findById({ _id: "5e6d0f3e8afae22ee0cc238c" }).select("friends");

 doc.friends.push({
        name: "Maria",
        email: "mariadomar@test.com",
        relatives: []
      });
await doc.save();
return doc ; // now it will be wrapped in promise and you can await the function


}
```